# Create Menu with a Multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am very new to c and c++. I am a c# programmer by day and rarely use arrays anymore. Nevertheless, I am working on a c++ project. I want to create a menu for a GUI that will resemble:

```
Menu Item 1
    Item 1.1
        Item 1.1.1
        Item 1.1.2
    Item 1.2
        Item 1.2.1
        Item 1.2.2
Menu Item 2
    Item 2.1
        Item 2.1.1
        Item 2.1.2
    Item 2.2
        Item 2.2.1
        Item 2.2.2
```

I am able to create a 2 dimensional version, but want to build a 3 dimensional version. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my 2 dimensional version:

```
    const char* menu[2][4] = 
    {
        {"Menu Item 1", "1.1 Item", "1.2 Item", "1.3 Item"},
        {"Menu Item 2", "2.1 Item", "2.2 Item", "2.3 Item"}

    };


    for(int i = 0; i < NUMOFCHO; i++){

        printf("%s\n\r", menu[i][0]);

        for(int k = 1; k < NUMOFITEMS; k++){
            printf("--%s\n\r", menu[i][k]);         

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think static arrays are the write data structure to use in this scenario. Take a look at [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: You could also use Tree Data structures to organize your Menu and items, but that will require recursive searching to access the data

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I don't think static arrays are *right*, either... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static arrays probably aren't the best data structure to use if you want any flexibility.

I suggest using a dynamically sized container like `std::vector`.

You'll often see menu structures like this using a "tree" type hierarchy, where each level of the menu has a name, and its children (sub menu items). Here's how you might go about using these concepts.

```
struct MenuItem
{
    // name of the menu item
    std::string name;

    // sub menu items
    std::vector<MenuItem> children;
};
```

Traversing the menu is easiest using recursion, here's a simple example.

```
void printMenu(const std::vector<MenuItem> &menu, int level) 
{
    // string containing tabs depending on the level of the menu
    std::string prefix( level, '\t' );

    // we're visiting the next menu level
    ++level;

    // iterate over this level of the menu
    for (const auto &item : menu) 
    {
        // display the item name
        std::cout << prefix << item.name << std::endl;

        // visit this level's children
        printMenu( item.children, level );
    }
}
```

Here's how you would initialize the sample menu structure provided.

```
std::vector<MenuItem> menu 
{
    {
        { 
            { "Menu Item 1" },
            { 
                {
                    { "Item 1.1" },
                    { 
                        {
                            { "Item 1.1.1" },
                            { {} }
                        },
                        {
                            { "Item 1.1.2" },
                            { {} }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    { "Item 1.2" },
                    {
                        {
                            { "Item 1.2.1" },
                            { {} }
                        },
                        {
                            { "Item 1.2.2" },
                            { {} }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        {
            { "Menu Item 2" },
            {
                {
                    { "Item 2.1" },
                    {
                        {
                            { "Item 2.1.1" },
                            { {} }
                        },
                        {
                            { "Item 2.1.2" },
                            { {} }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    { "Item 2.2" },
                    {
                        {
                            { "Item 2.2.1" },
                            { {} }
                        },
                        {
                            { "Item 2.2.2" },
                            { {} }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To access a specific menu item you can do the following.

```
// Item 2.2.1
std::string item = menu[ 1 ].children[ 1 ].children[ 0 ].name;
```

Or even adding an item after the structure has been initialized.

```
menu[ 1 ].children[ 1 ].children.push_back({
    { "Testing" }, // name
    { {} }         // children
});

/*
    Menu Item 1
        Item 1.1
                Item 1.1.1
                Item 1.1.2
        Item 1.2
                Item 1.2.1
                Item 1.2.2
    Menu Item 2
        Item 2.1
                Item 2.1.1
                Item 2.1.2
        Item 2.2
                Item 2.2.1
                Item 2.2.2
                Testing
*/
```

You can find a complete example [here](http://ideone.com/YKAI8Y).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are usually a poor choice for nested menus.

In my experience menus are usually linked together rather than in an array:

```
Menu1  
  Item1 --> Menu1.1
    |  
    v  
  Item2 --> Menu1.2
    |
    v
  Item3
```

I usually I have a menu *contain* items.  Each item can point to another submenu.  This allows for the case where an item does not have a submenu.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that I implemented a little while back in C.  It's set up to go as deep as 8 levels but there's technically no limit to depth. It's for embedded so it uses static memory for everything but it could easily be modified to use dynamic allocation.  You can find the sources on [my github page](https://github.com/rost0031/STM32491_CPLR/tree/master/Firmware/Application/src/app/menu) but I'll go through and explain them a little bit here.

The Menu is built around a k-ary tree (k-tree) which is implemented as a binary tree (b-tree). Unlike a regular k-tree where a node can have multiple children which would make sense for a menu system, since the system is memory and resource constrained, a binary tree makes more since.  It allows for statically allocated nodes without using fixed sized arrays to store child nodes. This implementation is a little confusing at first but is actually used in several resource sensitive systems such as the Linux kernel.

A regular k-tree is represented as:

```
struct t {
   int n;
   int numKids;
   struct t **kids;
}
```

and the resulting tree struture looks like:

```
   TOP
   |
   [ list of kids ]
   |     |      |
   k1    k2     k3
   |
   |
   [list of kids]
   |     |     |
   k1.1  k1.2  k1.3
```

This representation works if you have things like malloc but on an embedded
system where using malloc is anathema, if you want to add another child, use
a static array of limited length in addition to having to record the number
of kids in the array in the structure.

Instead, the following structure is used:

```
struct t {
   int n;
   struct t *firstChildNode;
   struct t *firstSiblingNode;
   struct t *trueParentNode;
   struct t *fakeParentNode;
};
```

and the tree representation looks like:

---

```
  [TOP NODE ] <-
  -----------   \
  ^|  ^          \
  ||  |           \ fP
  ||  |tP, fP      \
  ||  |_______  fS  \__________     fS
  ||  [NODE 2]------>[NODE 2.1]---------->NULL
  ||  ------- <------ ---------
  ||       |      tP      |
  ||       |fC            |fC
  ||fC     V              V
  ||      NULL          NULL
  ||
  |tP, fP
  ||
  |V_____
  [NODE1]
  -------
     ^
     |tP, fp
     |_________   fS
     [NODE 1.1] -----> NULL
         |
         |fC
         |
         V
       NULL
```

Where:

> - fP = fakeParentNode - this pointer is used to figure out where the actual
>      parent as it would appear in a classical k-ary tree.
> - tP = trueParentNode - this pointer is used to show where this node is actually attached since it could be either a child node of another
>     node or a sibling.
> - fC = firstChildNode - pointer to the first child node.
> - fS = firstSiblingNode - pointer to the first sibling node.

From any node, you can only access the first child or the first sibling, making this a classical b-tree. From that first child, you can access it's
children and siblings.  Likewise for the first sibling pointer. This way all
the nodes are stored in a list which can be comprised of statically allocated
structures.  The true and fake Parent pointers are for easily tracing the
ancestry of each child node.  The fake parent pointer is used to map a
classical k-tree structure over this b-tree.

There are several advantages to this seemingly confusing approach:

> - Each node is a fixed size and can be statically allocated.
> - No arrays are needed for representing child nodes.
> - Many algorithms can be easily expressed since it's just a b-tree.

This implementation of the menu is limited in that the functionality to remove nodes is not present since this doesn't seem to be a necessary feature for a menu.  To add a menu or menu item is very simple.  See example in menu_top.c

This design was inspired by https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2012/03/07/n-ary-trees-in-c/

Code for ktree.c:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "ktree.h"
#include "qp_port.h"                                        /* for QP support */
#include "project_includes.h"

/* Compile-time called macros ------------------------------------------------*/
Q_DEFINE_THIS_FILE                  /* For QSPY to know the name of this file */
DBG_DEFINE_THIS_MODULE( DBG_MODL_DBG );/* For debug system to ID this module */

/* Private typedefs ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private defines -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macros ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables and Local objects ---------------------------------------*/
static treeNode_t Menu1;
char *const Menu1Txt = "Menu 1";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem1;
   char *const MenuItem1_1Txt = "Menu Item 1.1";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem2;
   char *const MenuItem1_2Txt = "Menu Item 1.2";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem3;
   char *const MenuItem1_3Txt = "Menu Item 1.3";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem4;
   char *const MenuItem1_4Txt = "Menu Item 1.4";

static treeNode_t Menu2;
char *const Menu2Txt = "Menu 2";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem2_1;
   char *const MenuItem2_1Txt = "Menu Item 2.1";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem2_2;
   char *const MenuItem2_2Txt = "Menu Item 2.2";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem2_3;
   char *const MenuItem2_3Txt = "Menu Item 2.3";

   static treeNode_t MenuItem2_4;
   char *const MenuItem2_4Txt = "Menu Item 2.4";

static treeNode_t Menu3;
char *const Menu3Txt = "Menu 3";

   static treeNode_t Menu3_1;
   char *const Menu3_1Txt = "Menu 3_1";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_1_1;
      char *const MenuItem3_1_1Txt = "Menu Item 3.1.1";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_1_2;
      char *const MenuItem3_1_2Txt = "Menu Item 3.1.2";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_1_3;
      char *const MenuItem3_1_3Txt = "Menu Item 3.1.3";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_1_4;
      char *const MenuItem3_1_4Txt = "Menu Item 3.1.4";

   static treeNode_t Menu3_2;
   char *const Menu3_2Txt = "Menu 3_2";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_2_1;
      char *const MenuItem3_2_1Txt = "Menu Item 3.2.1";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_2_2;
      char *const MenuItem3_2_2Txt = "Menu Item 3.2.2";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_2_3;
      char *const MenuItem3_2_3Txt = "Menu Item 3.2.3";

      static treeNode_t MenuItem3_2_4;
      char *const MenuItem3_2_4Txt = "Menu Item 3.2.4";

   static treeNode_t Menu3_3;
   char *const Menu3_3Txt = "Menu 3_3";

      static treeNode_t Menu3_3_1;
      char *const Menu3_3_1Txt = "Menu 3_3_1";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_1_1;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_1_1Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.1.1";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_1_2;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_1_2Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.1.2";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_1_3;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_1_3Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.1.3";

      static treeNode_t Menu3_3_2;
      char *const Menu3_3_2Txt = "Menu 3_3_2";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_2_1;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_2_1Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.2.1";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_2_2;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_2_2Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.2.2";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_2_3;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_2_3Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.2.3";

      static treeNode_t Menu3_3_3;
      char *const Menu3_3_3Txt = "Menu 3_3_3";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_3_1;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_3_1Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.3.1";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_3_2;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_3_2Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.3.2";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_3_3;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_3_3Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.3.3";

      static treeNode_t Menu3_3_4;
      char *const Menu3_3_4Txt = "Menu 3_3_4";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_4_1;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_4_1Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.4.1";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_4_2;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_4_2Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.4.2";

         static treeNode_t MenuItem3_3_4_3;
         char *const MenuItem3_3_4_3Txt = "Menu Item 3.3.4.3";

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/******************************************************************************/
void KTREE_nodeCtor( treeNode_t *node )
{
   /* Initialize the root node */
   node->firstChildNode = NULL;
   node->firstSiblingNode = NULL;
   node->fakeParentNode = NULL;
   node->trueParentNode = NULL;
}

/******************************************************************************/
uint8_t KTREE_findDepth( treeNode_t *node, uint8_t currDepth )
{
   /* Make sure the node is not null.  If this happens, it's a bug. */
   if ( NULL == node ) {
      ERR_printf("!!!Node is null\n");
      return( 0 );
   }

   if ( NULL == node->fakeParentNode ) {
      /* If no fake parents exist, this is the top.  Return the calculated
       * depth */
      return( currDepth );
   } else {
      /* Parent exists; recurse after incrementing the depth */
      return (KTREE_findDepth( node->fakeParentNode, ++currDepth ));
   }
}

/******************************************************************************/
void KTREE_addChild(
      treeNode_t *childToAdd,
      treeNode_t *trueParentNode,
      treeNode_t *fakeParentNode
)
{
   /* Find the parent node */
   if ( NULL == trueParentNode ) {
      childToAdd->trueParentNode = NULL;
      childToAdd->fakeParentNode = NULL;
      return;
   } else if ( NULL == trueParentNode->firstChildNode ) {

      /* If the node where we want to add a child currently has no children,
       * add the child node here to the childNode field. */
      trueParentNode->firstChildNode = childToAdd;
//      dbg_slow_printf("whereToAddChild=0x%08x\n", (uint32_t )whereToAddChild);
   } else {
      /* Otherwise, add a sibling to the child of this node */
      KTREE_addNextSibling( childToAdd, trueParentNode->firstChildNode, fakeParentNode);
//      dbg_slow_printf("Adding a sibling to the child of node '%s'\n", trueParentNode->text);
   }
}

/******************************************************************************/
void KTREE_addNextSibling(
      treeNode_t *siblingToAdd,
      treeNode_t *trueParentNode,
      treeNode_t *fakeParentNode
)
{
   if( NULL == trueParentNode->firstSiblingNode ) {
      /* In the node being added, set its parents. */
      siblingToAdd->fakeParentNode = fakeParentNode;
      siblingToAdd->trueParentNode = trueParentNode;

      /* Set the empty firstSiblingNode pointer to new node being added. */
      trueParentNode->firstSiblingNode = siblingToAdd;
//      dbg_slow_printf("Added node '%s' as a sibling to node '%s'\n", siblingToAdd->text, trueParentNode->text);
   } else {
//      dbg_slow_printf("Sibling '%s' already exists here.  Trying next one\n", trueParentNode->text);
      KTREE_addNextSibling(siblingToAdd, trueParentNode->firstSiblingNode, fakeParentNode);
   }
}

/******************************************************************************/
void KTREE_printTree( treeNode_t *node, uint8_t level )
{
   if ( NULL == node ) {
//      dbg_slow_printf("Node at level %d is null, not printing\n", level);
      return;
   } else {
      KTREE_printNode( node, level );
   }

   if ( NULL != node->firstChildNode ) {
//      dbg_slow_printf("Child exists, descending one level\n");
      KTREE_printTree( node->firstChildNode, level+1 );
   }

   if ( NULL != node->firstSiblingNode ) {
//      dbg_slow_printf("Sibling exits, moving right\n");
      KTREE_printTree( node->firstSiblingNode, level );
   }

}

/******************************************************************************/
void KTREE_printNode( treeNode_t *node, uint8_t level )
{
   for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
      printf("*--");
   }
   printf("NodeText: %s\n", node->text);
   for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
      printf("*--");
   }
   printf("True Parent   pointer: 0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)node->trueParentNode);
   for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
      printf("*--");
   }
   printf("Fake Parent   pointer: 0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)node->fakeParentNode);
   for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
      printf("*--");
   }
   printf("First Sibling pointer: 0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)node->firstSiblingNode);
   for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
      printf("*--");
   }
   printf("First Child   pointer: 0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)node->firstChildNode);
}

/******************************************************************************/
void KTREE_fakeMenuTest( void )
{
   /* First Node */
   KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu1 );
   Menu1.text = Menu1Txt;

      /* Add a child node */
      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem1 );
      MenuItem1.text = MenuItem1_1Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem1, &Menu1, &Menu1 );

      /* Add siblings to that child node */
      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem2 );
      MenuItem2.text = MenuItem1_2Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem2, &Menu1, &Menu1 );

      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3 );
      MenuItem3.text = MenuItem1_3Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3, &Menu1, &Menu1 );

      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem4 );
      MenuItem4.text = MenuItem1_4Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem4, &Menu1, &Menu1 );

   /* Add another node at top level - it gets added as a sibling to the first node */
   KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu2 );
   Menu2.text = Menu2Txt;
   KTREE_addNextSibling( &Menu2, &Menu1, NULL );

      /* Add menu items to it as children  */
      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem2_1 );
      MenuItem2_1.text = MenuItem1_1Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem2_1, &Menu2, &Menu2 );

      /* Add siblings to that child node */
      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem2_2 );
      MenuItem2_2.text = MenuItem2_2Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem2_2, &Menu2, &Menu2 );

      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem2_3 );
      MenuItem2_3.text = MenuItem2_3Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem2_3, &Menu2, &Menu2 );

      KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem2_4 );
      MenuItem2_4.text = MenuItem2_4Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem2_4, &Menu2, &Menu2 );

   /* Add another node at top level - it gets added as a sibling to the first node */
   KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3 );
   Menu3.text = Menu3Txt;
   KTREE_addNextSibling( &Menu3, &Menu1, NULL );

      /* Add submenu nodes - it gets added as a sibling to the first node */
      KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3_1 );
      Menu3_1.text = Menu3_1Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &Menu3_1, &Menu3, &Menu3 );

         /* Add menu items to it as children  */
         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_1_1 );
         MenuItem3_1_1.text = MenuItem3_1_1Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_1_1, &Menu3_1, &Menu3_1 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_1_2 );
         MenuItem3_1_2.text = MenuItem3_1_2Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_1_2, &Menu3_1, &Menu3_1 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_1_3 );
         MenuItem3_1_3.text = MenuItem3_1_3Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_1_3, &Menu3_1, &Menu3_1 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_1_4 );
         MenuItem3_1_4.text = MenuItem3_1_4Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_1_4, &Menu3_1, &Menu3_1 );

      KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3_2 );
      Menu3_2.text = Menu3_2Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &Menu3_2, &Menu3, &Menu3 );

         /* Add menu items to it as children  */
         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_2_1 );
         MenuItem3_2_1.text = MenuItem3_2_1Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_2_1, &Menu3_2, &Menu3_2 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_2_2 );
         MenuItem3_2_2.text = MenuItem3_2_2Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_2_2, &Menu3_2, &Menu3_2 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_2_3 );
         MenuItem3_2_3.text = MenuItem3_2_3Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_2_3, &Menu3_2, &Menu3_2 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_2_4 );
         MenuItem3_2_4.text = MenuItem3_2_4Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_2_4, &Menu3_2, &Menu3_2 );

      KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3_3 );
      Menu3_3.text = Menu3_3Txt;
      KTREE_addChild( &Menu3_3, &Menu3, &Menu3 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3_3_1 );
         Menu3_3_1.text = Menu3_3_1Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &Menu3_3_1, &Menu3_3, &Menu3_3 );

            /* Add menu items to it as children  */
            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_1_1 );
            MenuItem3_3_1_1.text = MenuItem3_3_1_1Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_1_1, &Menu3_3_1, &Menu3_3_1 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_1_2 );
            MenuItem3_3_1_2.text = MenuItem3_3_1_2Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_1_2, &Menu3_3_1, &Menu3_3_1 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_1_3 );
            MenuItem3_3_1_3.text = MenuItem3_3_1_3Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_1_3, &Menu3_3_1, &Menu3_3_1 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3_3_2 );
         Menu3_3_2.text = Menu3_3_2Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &Menu3_3_2, &Menu3_3, &Menu3_3 );

            /* Add menu items to it as children  */
            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_2_1 );
            MenuItem3_3_2_1.text = MenuItem3_3_2_1Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_2_1, &Menu3_3_2, &Menu3_3_2 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_2_2 );
            MenuItem3_3_2_2.text = MenuItem3_3_2_2Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_2_2, &Menu3_3_2, &Menu3_3_2 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_2_3 );
            MenuItem3_3_2_3.text = MenuItem3_3_2_3Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_2_3, &Menu3_3_2, &Menu3_3_2 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3_3_3 );
         Menu3_3_3.text = Menu3_3_3Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &Menu3_3_3, &Menu3_3, &Menu3_3 );

            /* Add menu items to it as children  */
            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_3_1 );
            MenuItem3_3_3_1.text = MenuItem3_3_3_1Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_3_1, &Menu3_3_3, &Menu3_3_3 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_3_2 );
            MenuItem3_3_3_2.text = MenuItem3_3_3_2Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_3_2, &Menu3_3_3, &Menu3_3_3 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_3_3 );
            MenuItem3_3_3_3.text = MenuItem3_3_3_3Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_3_3, &Menu3_3_3, &Menu3_3_3 );

         KTREE_nodeCtor( &Menu3_3_4 );
         Menu3_3_4.text = Menu3_3_4Txt;
         KTREE_addChild( &Menu3_3_4, &Menu3_3, &Menu3_3 );

            /* Add menu items to it as children  */
            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_4_1 );
            MenuItem3_3_4_1.text = MenuItem3_3_4_1Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_4_1, &Menu3_3_4, &Menu3_3_4 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_4_2 );
            MenuItem3_3_4_2.text = MenuItem3_3_4_2Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_4_2, &Menu3_3_4, &Menu3_3_4 );

            KTREE_nodeCtor( &MenuItem3_3_4_3 );
            MenuItem3_3_4_3.text = MenuItem3_3_4_3Txt;
            KTREE_addChild( &MenuItem3_3_4_3, &Menu3_3_4, &Menu3_3_4 );

   KTREE_printTree( &Menu1, 0 );
}
```

Code for ktree.h:

```
#ifndef KTREE_H_
#define KTREE_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f4xx.h"                                 /* For STM32F4 support */
#include "Shared.h"

/* Exported defines ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/

typedef void (*pMenuFunction) (
      const char* dataBuf,
      uint16_t dataLen,
      CBMsgRoute dst
);

typedef struct treeNode {
   struct treeNode *fakeParentNode;
   struct treeNode *trueParentNode;
   struct treeNode *firstChildNode;
   struct treeNode *firstSiblingNode;
   char *text;
   char *selector;
   pMenuFunction actionToTake;
} treeNode_t;


/* Exported macros -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported variables --------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported functions --------------------------------------------------------*/


/**
 * @brief   Initialize the menu memory space with the contents of the menu
 *
 * This function initializes the menu application.
 *
 * @param [in]  iBus: I2C_Bus_t identifier for I2C bus to initialize
 *    @arg
 * @return: None
 */
void KTREE_nodeCtor( treeNode_t *node );

/**
 * @brief   Counts the depth (via fakeParentNode pointer) of the passed in
 * pointer to a node.
 *
 * Recursive function that counts it's own depth by traversing the tree up via
 * the fakeParentNode pointer and counting.
 *
 * @param [in]  *node: treeNode_t pointer to the node
 * @parem [in] currDepth: uint8_t value of the current depth.  Unless you want
 * to for some reason offset where you start counting from, pass in 0 here.
 * @return: uint8_t depth of the current node.
 */
uint8_t KTREE_findDepth( treeNode_t *node, uint8_t currDepth );

/**
 * @brief   Adds a child node to a passed in parent node.
 *
 * This function adds a child node to a passed in parent node after doing some
 * initial checking of both nodes.
 *
 * @param [in] childNode: treeNode_t* pointer to the node to be added as a child
 * @parem [in] trueParentNone: treeNode_t* pointer to the node that the child
 * node will be directly attached to because it may appear as a sibling node or
 * an actual child node.
 * @parem [in] fakeParentNone: treeNode_t* pointer to the node that indicates
 * the "regular" tree depth of this child node.
 * @return: None
 */
void KTREE_addChild(
      treeNode_t *childToAdd,
      treeNode_t *trueParentNode,
      treeNode_t *fakeParentNode
);

/**
 * @brief   Adds a sibling node to a passed in parent node.
 *
 * This function adds a sibling node to a passed in parent node by checking if
 * the child node of the trueParentNode is used up and if it is, it recursively
 * calls itself with the used node as a trueParentNode parameter until it finds
 * the last sibling.  It then adds the sibling node there and sets the
 * fakeParentNode.
 *
 * @param [in] childNode: treeNode_t* pointer to the node to be added as a child
 * @parem [in] trueParentNone: treeNode_t* pointer to the node that the child
 * node will be directly attached to because it may appear as a sibling node or
 * an actual child node.
 * @parem [in] fakeParentNone: treeNode_t* pointer to the node that indicates
 * the "regular" tree depth of this child node.
 * @return: None
 */
void KTREE_addNextSibling(
      treeNode_t *siblingToAdd,
      treeNode_t *trueParentNode,
      treeNode_t *fakeParentNode
);

void KTREE_printTree( treeNode_t *node, uint8_t level );

void KTREE_printNode( treeNode_t *node, uint8_t level );

void KTREE_fakeMenuTest( void );
```

I don't want to post the rest of the code here (it's already a lot) but take a look at the rest of that directory in my link to see how it was used.  menu.c/h uses the ktree to set up an actual menu and uses it.